# ngx-bootstrap ShowIndicators = false not working

Tags: angular, carousel, ngx-bootstrap

we are using the carousel with some HTML markup (not images). We need to turn off the indicators, but `[showIndicators]="false"` does not hide them.

We have tried passing in a `bool variable`, a hard coded `false`, etc. We even tried to hide the indicators with external CSS, but the indicators are still showing. Any ideas?

Here is our code:

```
<carousel [(activeSlide)]="activeSlide" [interval]="false" [showIndicators]="showIndicators">
...
</carousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

go to your project main index.html file and write this css

```
.carousel-control.left {
    display: none;
}
.carousel-control.right {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this example working:

```
<carousel [showIndicators]="false">
    <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="content">
                <h1>{{slide.title}}</h1>
                <div class="content" [innerHtml]="slide.content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

Also `showIndicators` is `false`.

This is the full example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/w89089qy8

Comment: Thanks, it does work. I now realise that I was trying to hide the arrows, as well as the indicators. However `[showIndicators]="false"`only hides the indicators, not the arrows. Thanks for your help man.